# Issue passing data from API call in SwiftUI MVVM pattern

Tags: ios, swift, api, rest, swiftui

been going back and forth for 2 days trying to figure this out before posting and still hitting a wall.

Created an API specific class, a ViewModel, and a View and trying to shuttle data back and forth and while I see the API call is successful and I decode it without issue on logs, it never reflects on the UI or View.

As far as I see I appear to be trying to access the data before it's actually available. All help greatly appreciated!

API Class:

```
import Combine
import Foundation

class CrunchbaseApi:ObservableObject
{
    @Published var companies:[Company] = [Company]()
    @Published var singleCompany:Company?

        
    func retrieve(company:String) async
    {
        let SingleEntityURL:URL = URL(string:"https://api.crunchbase.com/api/v4/entities/organizations/\(company)?card_ids=fields&user_key=**********REMOVED FOR SECURITY*****************")!
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:SingleEntityURL){ data, response, error in

            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            
            if let data = data{
                do {
                    self.singleCompany = try decoder.decode(Company.self, from: data)
                } catch  {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    
    func retrieveCompanyList()
    {
        //declare
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
import Combine
import Foundation

class CompanyViewModel: ObservableObject
{
    var crunchbase:CrunchbaseApi = CrunchbaseApi()
    @Published var singleCompany:Company?
    
    
    func retrieveCompany(company:String) async
    {
        await self.crunchbase.retrieve(company: company)
        self.singleCompany = crunchbase.singleCompany
        
    }
    
}
```

View:

```
import SwiftUI

struct CompanyView: View
{
    @State var companyViewModel:CompanyViewModel = CompanyViewModel()
    
    
    var body: some View
    {
        
        NavigationView
        {
            VStack
            {
                Text("Company ID: \(companyViewModel.singleCompany?.id ?? "NOTHING")")
              //  Text("Company Name: \(companyViewModel.companyName)")
             //   Text("Company Summary: \(companyViewModel.companyDescription)")
             //   Text("Logo URL: \(companyViewModel.companyLogoURL)")
            }.navigationTitle("Company")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my advice is, do not **nest** `ObservableObject` it does not work as you expect. Just use one model, e.g: `CrunchbaseApi` and adjust it to do what `CompanyViewModel` does, that is, move `retrieveCompany` into it.

Comment: Your API can simply return the values instead of assigning it to ObservableObject. This means VM calls the API, gets the data and then VM assigns the @Published property to the result received from the API.

Comment: `async` is for when you are using either the built in `async await` methods or when you are creating your own using the `Concurrency` methods and objects. `func retrieve(company:String)` should not be labeled `async`. Try [Meet async await](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10132)

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption about accessing the data to early is correct. But there are more things going on here.

- just declaring a function `async` like your `retrieve` func doesn´t make it async.
- using a nested `Observable` class with `@Published` will not update the view
- `Observable` classes should have either an `@StateObject` or an `@ObservableObject` property wrapper. Depending on if the class is injected or created in the view

---

Possible solution:

Move the function into the viewmodel:

```
class CompanyViewModel: ObservableObject
{

    @Published var singleCompany:Company?
    
    
    func retrieve(company:String)
    {
        let SingleEntityURL:URL = URL(string:"https://api.crunchbase.com/api/v4/entities/organizations/\(company)?card_ids=fields&user_key=**********REMOVED FOR SECURITY*****************")!
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:SingleEntityURL){ data, response, error in

            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            
            if let data = data{
                do {
                    self.singleCompany = try decoder.decode(Company.self, from: data)
                } catch  {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    
}
```

Change the View to hold the viewmodel as `@StateObject`, also add an `.onApear` modifier to load the data:

```
struct CompanyView: View
{
    @StateObject var companyViewModel:CompanyViewModel = CompanyViewModel()
    
    
    var body: some View
    {
        
        NavigationView
        {
            VStack
            {
                Text("Company ID: \(companyViewModel.singleCompany?.id ?? "NOTHING")")
              //  Text("Company Name: \(companyViewModel.companyName)")
             //   Text("Company Summary: \(companyViewModel.companyDescription)")
             //   Text("Logo URL: \(companyViewModel.companyLogoURL)")
            }.navigationTitle("Company")
            .onAppear {
               companyViewModel.retrieve(company: "whatever")
             }
        }
    }
}
```